# Type of telescope on Star Trek

Tags: telescope

In the first episode of *Star Trek: Discovery*, we learn that Captain Georgiou has an old-fashioned telescope in her ready room. Michael Burnham inherits it a bit later in the season. I wonder if anyone can identify exactly which telescope it is. What's the model and manufacturer? It seems to be an equatorial-mounted refractor with a finder scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this fits this site, maybe better for TV & Movies, but it doesn't appear to be a historic or current telescope.

[This website advertises that they sell that model](https://www.spotern.com/en/spot/tv/star-trek-discovery/90656/le-telescope-du-capitaine-han-bo-michelle-yeoh-dans-star-trek-discovery) Based on the look and it is similar.   It may be a  nice telescope but it's nothing special.  Certainly not worthy of being a family heirloom passed down for generations, so that doesn't really make sense and it's not a perfect match either, though it's similar.

[image]

[Larger image here](http://media.agonybooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/25202409/00002247.jpg).

It not being a perfect match and there being virtually no references to that telescope representing something real, it's likely not a historical telescope, which is fine.   It could be a future telescope and still be in Captain Georgiou's family for generations.  That would work because they used it in the show to look at things the ship couldn't sense due to some kind of obscuring.  A historic telescope probably wouldn't be able to do that.

Ultimately, I think Signourney Weaver as Lt. Madison said it best.

[image]

Comment: "Not worthy of being an heirloom" is an odd idea, as nothing starts out being an heirloom.  It becomes an "heirloom" when someone gives it to a later generation and they hold on to it (typically for sentiment, not value) and later it becomes both a sentimental heirloom *and* possibly a rare *surviving* example of an *old* telescope (as it would be in the period the show was set in).

Comment: @StephenG  I have a tough time seeing a $300 telescope being passed down through about 10 generations as a prized family possession.      Maybe it's the skeptic in me.

Comment: Having had to sit through innumerable episodes of Antiques Roadshow I am no longer surprised by the variety of mundane items passed down from past to present.  It's not that they even had much intrinsic value, but that someone valued them and keeping them became almost a duty for some people.  Depends on your family and the individuals I'm sure.  Also keep in mind you can skip generations (grandparent to grandchild kinda thing).  The fact is these things happen, as mind-boggling as it is for me, who attaches almost no sentiment to objects.